# Pandas query() with math functions

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following dataframe where I would like to use `query` to keep only rows where `floor(A/100)` is above a certain threshold:

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'A':[177,887,945,412,231,314],
         'B':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
})
```

I tried:

```
import math
df.query('math.floor(A/100) > 2')
```

Python throws `UndefinedVariableError: name 'math' is not defined`. I guess the way `query()` handles the string is not able to parse  `math` as a module prefix. Any ideas?

A pipeable solution is strictly preferred.

Answer (score 2):

Import `math` module and remove `math` from `query` command.

```
import math

In [1909]: df.query('floor(A/100) > 2')
Out[1909]: 
     A  B
1  887  3
2  945  6
3  412  9
5  314  4
```

Comment: I don't think you need to import math

Comment: Interesting. On my sytem this throws ValueError floor is not a supported function. @Mayank Which pandas version are you running? Mine is 0.22.0

Comment: @SAFEX Mine is `1.0.3`.